# How to get a list of programs that have connected to the Apache socket?

Tags: php, apache, sockets, tcp, fsockopen

I have a LAMP server running. External services connect to this server (services running on iPhone). 
I want, from a php script, to get a list of all the services that have connected to the Apache server... How do I do it? Should I use fsockopen?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want a list of 'services'? The most you're going to get without additional information is a list of IP addresses and ports - is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
<? 
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

... otherwise try the "TOP" program from SSH. (not sure how to use that through PHP... `<? 'top' ?>` maybe??)